# Scrolling through pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello there Stackoverflow.
I have a little job for my website i can't figure out on my own.

I have a box on the right, where i want all my sponsors, but instead of making the box really long, i just want a simple "slideshow" where it just fades into a picture, it stays for 3 seconds, and it fades into another picture. They're gonna be 90x90 most of them, however some may be different sizes and that shouldn't screw up.

I have a picture demonstrating, if you didn't get the concept from my poor english.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVL9d.jpg

1=The sponsor picture. At this box it should slide between the different sponsors.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this on [my company's home page](http://www.edfinancial.com). Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/philliptune/pen/mgJxf/) for it. I like using CSS whenever possible and minimize the javascript.

The DOM:

```
<div class="slides_container">
  <div class="slide"><img src="img1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img3.jpg"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img4.jpg"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img5.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS: Use the `transition` property to fade in and out. (Remember, you need to use vendor prefixes on `transition` to work with various browsers.)

```
.slides_container {
    height:90px;
    width:90px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
    .slides_container .slide {
        position:absolute;
        visibility:hidden;
        opacity:0;
        transition:opacity 1s ease, visibility 0s ease 1s;
    }
    .slides_container .slide.active {
        visibility:visible;
        opacity:1;
        transition:opacity 1s ease;
    }
```

The Javascript: This can be done without jQuery, but I'll use it here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /*make sure the first element shows up*/
    $('.slides_container .slide:first-child').addClass("active");
    var active_slide = 0,
        dom_slides = $('.slides_container .slide'),
        num_slides = dom_slides.length,
        myInterval = setInterval(function(){
            if(active_slide>(num_slides*5+1))
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            changeSlide(++active_slide);
        },6000);
    function changeSlide(slide) {
        if((slide = slide%num_slides)<0) slide+=num_slides;
        dom_slides.removeClass('active').eq(slide).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

(On my code, I added `if(active_slide>(num_slides*5+1)) clearInterval(myInterval);` That just stops the rotation after 5 cycles - so it's not just running forever. You can just delete those two lines if you want it to be infinite.)

Okay, explanation:

The CSS will apply `visibility:hidden; opacity:0;` to all of the `.slide` DOM elements. On `.active` state, the opacity transitions from 0 to 1 for 1 second (`transition:opacity 1s ease;`). Remember when `.active` state goes away, you need to delay the `visibility` for 1s so the `opacity` can transition, hence the `visibility 0s ease 1s;`.

In the Javascript, `num_slides` will count the number of `.slide` DOM elements; That variable will later be used with a [modulo (%)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation): `slide % num_slides` returns a whole number from 0 to the number of slides minus 1. We'll later use jQuery's `.eq()` method to select each DOM element in turn and apply the `.active` class to it.

Comment: My first picture appears, then it just stays there without changing. I pretty much copy pasted and edited the src's of my files ofc. Any ideas what i did wrong?

Comment: Hmm, it would help if I actually tested my code before posting it here, hah. I will check it.

Comment: Alright, got it fixed and tests good. Here it is in codepen. http://cdpn.io/mgJxf. I created an `interval` variable in the javascript to make it easier to edit. (4000ms = 4s)

Comment: Works like a charm now. Note you have given me two different codes from your codepen and your post here. I figured it out though. I'm having a problem making my pictures centered in the box i have the slides, because the pictures are different sizes. Do you have any advice for that? Otherwise i'll just have to figure it out for myself. Thanks alot for the code!

Comment: Yeah, I kept updating my answer so much I thought the stackoverflow gods might get angry. Centering will all be a part of your CSS: `.slide { ... text-align:center; }`, or `.slide img { display:block; width:/*whatever*/; margin:0 auto; }`. Did that answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, do not forget you need the jquery library.  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F28jd/6/) working jsfiddle example with images from google.

Html:

```
<img src="" id="current" alt="" />
<ul class="slider">
    <li><img src="http://p4.storage.canalblog.com/49/16/976515/75966520.gif" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.graycon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Sponsor-Logos4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://forum.mmaglobal.com/files/mobilemarketingforum.com/Image/SponsorFooter_SanDiego_v9_2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul.slider { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="/libraries/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idx = 0;
    var interval = 3000;
    var images = $('ul.slider li img');
    setInterval(function(){
        idx++;
        $('img#current').fadeOut(function () { 
            $(this).attr('src', $(images[idx%images.length]).attr('src')).fadeIn()                
        });
    }, interval);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Something seems not to work. No pictures appears. I will leave som pics here of my code, 2 seconds. http://i.imgur.com/ZBoZTZm.png - http://i.imgur.com/gqXyIcE.png

Comment: in the demo link? the first three seconds there is no picture. If you would like that set the initial src attribute of the img tag

Comment: Nice, if you would like to adjust the speed, take a look at the fadeIn() and fadeOut() documentation http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: The problem is Mark, there dosen't appear any pictures. Did i do something wrong? that's why i posted the pics, sorry for not making it clear

Comment: Well you nee the latest jquery library, you're including 1.3.1 while my fiddle example includes 1.8.3 as shown in the bar on the left. Secondly, check the src's of your images, are you certain they are right?

Comment: Okay i updated the library, and double checked the src of my images. Still not working though

Comment: Ok @NotKimJongUn i think it has something to do with your script tag. Take a look at mine, i'v updated my answer in the jQuery part.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use a jquery slider. I have experience with jquery.cycle. It has many features and it's easy to install

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/